# Solidity: TypeError: Function declared as view, but this expression modifies the state and thus requires non-payable (the default) or payable

Tags: ethereum, solidity, bep20

I have been trying to create a smart contract/Token, will deploy this on the Binance Smart Chain test net. I followed some documentation and started with this. I am getting into this function issue. Function is declared as Read only. Here is the source code

The function is changing the state of the Owner Address, what is the other option to declare it as read only

---

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

//import "Context.sol";
//import "IBEP20.sol";
//import "SafeMath.sol";
//import "Ownable.sol";

contract SampleTaken {
    
    
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    
    uint public totalSupply = 1000000 * 10 ** 18;
    string public name ="Sample Token";
    string public symbol ="KJA";
    uint public decimals = 18;
    
    /** Events aailable for the Contract**/
    
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    
    constructor(){
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }
    
    function balanceOf(address _ownerAddress) public view returns (uint){
        return balances[_ownerAddress];
    }
    
    function transfer(address _toAddress, uint _noOfTokens) public view returns (bool){
    require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= _noOfTokens, "Total balance is less than the number of Tokens asked for !!!");
    balances[_toAddress] +=_noOfTokens;
    balances[msg.sender] -= _noOfTokens;
    emit Transfer(msg.sender,_toAddress, _noOfTokens);
    return true;
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool){
     require(balanceOf(_from) >= _value, "Balance is less than the number of Tokens asked for !!!");
    // require(allowance[_from][msg.sender] >= _value, "Allowance too low");
     balances[_to] += _value;
     balances[_from] -= _value;   
     
     emit Transfer (_from, _to, _value);
     return true;
     
     }    
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Your `transfer()` function is declared as a `view` function.

> *Functions can be declared view in which case they promise not to modify the state.*

Source: [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/contracts.html#view-functions)

But these lines (within the `transfer()` function) modify the state:

```
balances[_toAddress] +=_noOfTokens;
balances[msg.sender] -= _noOfTokens;
emit Transfer(msg.sender,_toAddress, _noOfTokens);
```

---

If you want your function to modify the state, it cannot be a `view` (nor a `pure`) function - and you need to remove the `view` modifier:

```
function transfer(address _toAddress, uint _noOfTokens) public returns (bool){
```

Comment: Thanks Petr. Went thru the documentation, looks like View can not be used in this case. However as per my understanding, declaring a function as view makes them non accessible from outside the contract, kind of securing the function. Is my understanding incorrect? Thanks

Comment: @user3161840 "view makes them non accessible from outside the contract" - that's incorrect... If you want to limit which addresses can execute the function, you can use the [ownable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol#L42) approach. The OpenZeppelin implementation only validates against one address (stored in the `_owner` property), but you can also validate against multiple (stored in an array or in a mapping)... If you don't want any other contract or user to execute the function, you need to mark it as `private` or `internal`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `view` or `pure` keyword from the function declaration and keep only `public returns`

Change

```
function transfer(address _toAddress, uint _noOfTokens) public view returns (bool)
```

to

```
function transfer(address _toAddress, uint _noOfTokens) public returns (bool)
```

Changed method:

```
function transfer(address _toAddress, uint _noOfTokens) public returns (bool){
    require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= _noOfTokens, "Total balance is less than the number of Tokens asked for !!!");
    balances[_toAddress] +=_noOfTokens;
    balances[msg.sender] -= _noOfTokens;
    emit Transfer(msg.sender,_toAddress, _noOfTokens);
    return true;
    }
```